# Unable to click on country name into android app ( Selenium , Java and Appium )

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium-android

I am unable to click on country in android app in appium selenium java automation. I have tried different xpath but unable to succeed. I am passing country name, which I want to select, but it is not working, please help me.

I have tried following code:

```
    List<MobileElement> countryName = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView"));
                 //List <MobileElement> countryName = driver.findElements (By.className ("android.widget.TextView"));
    
       for (int i = 0; i < countryName.size(); i++) {
                     if (countryName.get(i).getText().equalsIgnoreCase(country)) {
     
                         countryName.get(i).click();
                       
                     }
               }[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I have tried following xpath to click on direct country or send country name
```

> @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.TextView[@text='Costa
> Rica']")
> public static WebElement CostaRica;
>
> ```
> @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[2]/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.ScrollView")
> public static WebElement sendCountryName;
> ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try following xpath,

```
//*[contains(@text,'Costa Rica')]
```

Mostly it work, but let me know if it worked or not.